# Hidden controls appearing in web instance[Labview]

Tags: web, publishing, labview

I have created an application in which the vi has some controls and these controls are useful only during the development and on special instance can be unlocked in the application. i basically use app.kind property node to determine what environment the vi is running in and suitably hide/unhide the controls.

I have the application published on the web using the NI Web publishing tool. The computer which hosts the app works fine(and these controls remain invisible) but these controls can be sen on the web page. The vi is in "Embedd" mode. As a workaround i have pushed these controls some distance away and hence avoided the user from knowing about it. but this introduces the problem that i cannot view these controls when i unlock them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which release of LabView are you running?

Comment: @ErikOlson its LabVIEW 2012.

Answer (score 1):

You have built a stand-alone application and enabled web server, correct?
Are you sure the web panel is connecting to the stand-alone application (app.kind=2)
and it is not reaching the development LabView (app.kind=1) still listening on that web server port?

I would add an indicator to display the value of app.kind at all times.

What happens if you toggle the hidden fields on and off? I would add a button to do this on the vi.
Do they disappear/reappear reliably in the window where you have control?

Also, you said this was in Embedded mode - but are you also transferring control to the web page?

Those are some approaches I'd try to help pin this down.

Comment: Hi Erik. i did these tests and they were ok. i.e app.kind indicator shows "Run-time system" on the web interface too. i ran with a conditional diagram disable(using RUN_TIME_ENGINE == True) too but with no similar effect. i transfer control when the user asks for it. since that is what the customer wants. and about reliably hiding/unhiding controls i have the same issue. but this i will look into more detail because there is a control and i dont seem to find any issue with that, but will confirm nonetheless.

Comment: and about your first comment, yes its a stand alone app which is published on the web. i close the development system(and labview) if i need to test. this actually happened after i shipped the installer to the customer.. [LINK](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Hidden-controls-appearing-in-web-instance/m-p/2543391#M770478) to the post on forums.ni. you can see the two images of how i have written the code.